# Anaconda channel for installing python 2.7

Tags: macos, conda

Since I have a mac with a M1 chip, I couldn't get Tensorflow installed using the regular version of anaconda, therefore, I installed conda using `miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh` instead. However now I cannot create an environment with python 2.7.

```
conda create --name osmEnv python=2.7
```

I end up with the following error,

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=2.7

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

 To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
 looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

As suggested in the comments for adding a new channel (orginal question), I also tried using the anaconda channel,

```
conda create --name osmEnv -c anaconda python=2.7
```

Which resulted in the same error. Any ideas how to get python 2.7 installed.

Comment: Use `-c <channel name>`. E.g. `conda create -c conda-forge ...`

Comment: Is this correct `conda create -c conda-forge --name osmEnv python=2.7`, didnt work though

Comment: Are you sure that there is a compatible Python version available through Conda?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Not natively.** Python 2.7 was sunsetted prior to release of the **osx-arm64** platform, so there isn't any such build. One could try requesting such a build on [the Conda Forge Python feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues), but even if someone did that you'd still face the issue that most Python packages will also lack **osx-arm64** builds for Python 2.7.

**Emulate through Rosetta**. Apple provides an x86_64 emulator, [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861), which will run x86_64 binaries, such as what would be installed with Conda environments using an **osx-64** subdir. One can create environments with such a `subdir` setting with something like:

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n py27 python=2.7  # include other packages here

# ensure that future package installs in this env stick to 'osx-64'
conda activate py27
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
```

Just be mindful to always have the environment activated when installing any additional packages. Rosetta should automatically kick in when launching `python` with such an environment activated.

Comment: Just tested on M1 pro, seems to work decently!

Comment: @Hiram thanks for confirming. Please let me know if there's anything that could be clarified here.

Comment: Success create environment py27 with python=2.7, but when switch to py27, python --version still shows 3.9.7.

Comment: @Harrison Ensure that your environment is activated correctly (e.g., check PATH before and after). A more robust test that is not dependent on shell state would be `conda run -n py27 python --version`.

Comment: Sad that Python 2.7 doesn't have at least one legacy build on `conda-forge`. Nobody is looking for updates or support or new packages, just for a reproducible legacy environment available from a freely accessible channel.

Comment: @JasonS what's the problem with running it in emulation? Also, Conda Forge is a community project - users are welcome to submit builds. The problem is that all architecture-specific packages have to be built *per Python version*. That means it's not as simple as just having a `conda-forge/osx-arm64::python=2.7` - tons of other packages would need rebuilds to also be native. I think the best that could be hoped for is native Python + Pip, and then expect to Pip install everything else.