# Creating python 2 environment with anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, conda

I am trying to create a PY27 environment in anaconda on a Mac (Montery 12.6.4) using the following code

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

When I try this I get the following"

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.8.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.8.0
WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.9.0.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.9.0
done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=2.7
```

Any help is much appreciated

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67569068/570918 But also, why do you want the `anaconda` package? That is a huge set of packages, most you will never use.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. But I am now getting the same error message when trying to install Spyder. Any ideas on how to install spyder? Thanks